# Aspect ratio constraint not getting altered

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

I have two kinds of image 1.Square and other 2. Images with ratio 3:4. And I get information about the aspect ratio of incoming image in advance(which is in `currentImageAspectRatio`).
I want to handle both kind of images in one UIImageView.

**In Storyboard**

I have added both 1:1 and 3:4 constraints to my imageView, and then unchecked `Installed` for 3:4 constraint.

**In Code**

My `viewDidLoad` has

```
if currentImageAspectRatio == .square{
    // Already Square
} else {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([squareImageConstraint])
    imageView.addConstraint(threeByFourImageConstraint)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I also tried to put same code in `viewWillAppear:` but that too didn't work.

I am confused if there is something wrong I am doing.

And also I need suggestion on where is the most ideal place to do such stuff like altering constraints(I was thinking to use `viewWillLayoutSubviews`).

Comment: you have added threeByFourImageConstraint and again said that you have uncheked it. i don't get it. dude

Comment: Try this code in `viewDidAppear` or you are thinking in right way you can do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` also

Comment: I had previously tried calling the code from `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, `viewWillAppear ` and `viewDidLoad` and finally now it worked by calling it from  `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Thanks @PiyushPatel

Comment: Should I delete this question as I think it was my mistake??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the same code from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` worked for me.